# Installing pgRouting on Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: installation, pgrouting, ubuntu

Here are the steps i did:

1. Added ppa to repository sources
2. in synaptic marked all pgrouting for postgres 8.4
3. apply (everything was ok)
4. restarted postgres

But, i just tried a simple function shortest_path and it seems to do not recognise it:

> ERROR:  function shortest_path(text, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT * FROM shortest_path('

This is the query:

> SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT
>   gid as id,source::integer as
>   source,target::integer as
>   target,length::double precision as
>   cost FROM topologia'::text,1, 2,
>   false, false);

Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

I just found the solution.

After the steps above, one has to actually add the functions to the postgresql database:

> $ sudo su postgres
>
> $ psql -d routing -f
>   /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core.sql
>
> $ psql -d routing -f
>   /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core_wrappers.sql
>
> $ psql -d routing -f
>   /usr/share/postlbs/routing_topology.sql